# Updating terraform (.tf) files using Python

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to update terraform templates using python, although I am having some issues trying to find a module (like PyYAML to update yml files).

My aim is to update the terraform files present in a git repo, and create a pull request, which when merged would trigger a pipeline to implement the changes.

Example .tf file:

```
variable "variable_1" {}
variable "variable_2" {}

locals {
  temp_locals = 0
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT" {
  name = "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user.name1"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" {
}
```

Want to add arn of user.name2 in this file.

Comment: HCL is the name of the markup language the terraform uses. A google search shows a couple python modules for parsing HCL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [edit tfvars file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697934/edit-tfvars-file-using-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is currently no Python implementation of Terraform's underlying syntax HCL which can support surgical modification to an existing file, because that requires preserving information that a typical HCL parser will not retain, such as comments and the ordering of arguments within blocks.

Another option is to use a lesser-used feature of Terraform called [Override Files](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html), which allow you to write a new file that overrides part of an existing file. This mechanism exists specifically for this sort of situation where you want to use the content from a file written by humans but override part of it with content generated by a machine.

If you take your given example code as `example.tf` then you can put another file on disk next to it called `example_override.tf.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "resource": {
    "aws_iam_role": {
      "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT": {
        "assume_role_policy": "{\n\t\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n\t\"Statement\": [\n\t  {\n\t\t\"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\",\n\t\t\"Condition\": {\n\t\t  \"Bool\": {\n\t\t\t\"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent\": \"true\"\n\t\t  }\n\t\t},\n\t\t\"Principal\": {\n\t\t  \"AWS\": [\n\t\t\t\"arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user.name2\"\n\t\t  ]\n\t\t},\n\t\t\"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n\t\t\"Sid\": \"\"\n\t  }\n\t]\n  }"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because this additional file uses [Terraform's alternative JSON syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html), it is easy to generate from any language that has a JSON serializer available, including Python. Terraform itself will read both files and take the `assume_role_policy` from the override file as overriding the corresponding one in the base file, as described in [Merging Behavior](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html#merging-behavior). You can then leave the original HCL file unmodified, avoiding issues with interfering with human-oriented formatting decisions in that file.

---

The Go implementation of HCL, which is the canonical one and the one that Terraform itself uses, has a package [`hclwrite`](http://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite) which is a specialized API for directly modifying existing HCL source code while preserving all of the unmodified tokens and their ordering. Therefore a program written in *Go* could potentially achieve a result like what you were looking for using that package:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    hcl "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite"
    "github.com/zclconf/go-cty/cty"
)

func main() {
    // In a real program, use ioutil.ReadFile to read a file from disk.
    // But for this example, I will use a const string.
    src := []byte(oldSource)
    f, diags := hclwrite.ParseConfig(src, "example.tf", hcl.Pos{Line: 1, Column: 1})
    if diags.HasErrors() {
        log.Fatal(diags)
    }

    for _, block := range f.Body().Blocks() {
        if block.Type() != "resource" {
            continue
        }
        if labels := block.Labels(); len(labels) < 2 || labels[0] != "aws_iam_role" || labels[1] != "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT" {
            continue
        }

        block.Body().SetAttributeValue("assume_role_policy", cty.StringVal(newPolicy))
    }

    // In a real program, maybe write these bytes to a file on disk.
    fmt.Println(string(f.Bytes()))
}

const oldSource = `
variable "variable_1" {}
variable "variable_2" {}

locals {
  temp_locals = 0
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT" {
  name = "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user.name1"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" {
}
`

const newPolicy = `
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {
          "Bool": {
            "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
          }
        },
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user.name2"
          ]
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
  }
`
```

The output of this program does, however, demonstrate one of the limitations of automatic generation of a language that's primarily designed to be written and read by humans:

```
variable "variable_1" {}
variable "variable_2" {}

locals {
  temp_locals = 0
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT" {
  name = "MY_AWS_ACCOUNT"

  assume_role_policy = "\n{\n\t\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n\t\"Statement\": [\n\t  {\n\t\t\"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\",\n\t\t\"Condition\": {\n\t\t  \"Bool\": {\n\t\t\t\"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent\": \"true\"\n\t\t  }\n\t\t},\n\t\t\"Principal\": {\n\t\t  \"AWS\": [\n\t\t\t\"arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:user/user.name2\"\n\t\t  ]\n\t\t},\n\t\t\"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n\t\t\"Sid\": \"\"\n\t  }\n\t]\n  }\n"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" {
}
```

As humans, we can make subjective decisions about how to format things for readability, but `hclwrite` has just defaulted to using the quoted string form for this string, which in this case is a poor choice that a human author would likely not have made.