# edit tfvars file using python

Tags: python, scripting, terraform

I don't know whether I'm asking this is the right group, but is there a way to edit a .tfvars using python. For example, I have a .tfvars file with the some variables with following values:

```
owner ='operations'
port_number='80'
```

I would like to edit `port number = '22'` and to use `gcp_region = 'us_central2'`
can I open,edit the file and save it using python?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your .tfvars files to JSON.

Terraform supports JSON input files seamlessly, using the extension `.tfvars.json`.

> This syntax is useful when generating portions of a configuration programmatically

See: [Terraform JSON Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/language/syntax/json) and [Terraform input variables](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files)

You can read the files in HCL using the python-hcl2 library to convert to JSON. Then read, edit and write the JSON in Python.
For example:

```
import json
import hcl2

with open("vars.tfvars", "r") as file_in:
  data = hcl2.load(file_in)

data["port_number"] = "22"
data["gcp_region"] = "us_central2"

with open("vars.tfvars.json", "w") as file_out:
  file_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

The suggested `python-hcl2` library is only able to read HCL files. If you are set on using HCL, Golang is the recommended method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pyhcl](https://pypi.org/project/pyhcl/), which is a parser for HCL (HashiCorp Configuration Language):

> This module is intended to be used in mostly the same way that one
> would use the json module in python, and load/loads/dumps are
> implemented.
>
> ```
> import hcl
>
> with open('file.hcl', 'r') as fp:
>     obj = hcl.load(fp)
> ```

EDIT: From the [project GitHub page](https://github.com/virtuald/pyhcl):

> pyhcl does not support HCL2 (which is what modern terraform uses). You
> might try https://pypi.org/project/python-hcl2/ instead (though I've
> never personally tried it).

So if this is your case, check the [python-hcl2](https://pypi.org/project/python-hcl2/) project.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to edit the .tfvars using python, but since python works with json, I converted the .tfvars file into tfvars.json which is still an allowed format in terraform and used that within my python script instead. I hope this will be helpful to people out there.